Android Studio Watch Face Format XML ImageConfiguration to background
<UserConfigurations>
<ColorConfiguration id="themeColor" displayName="color_label" defaultValue="0">
  <ColorOption id="0" displayName="color_theme_0" colors="#ffbe0b #fb5607 #ff006e #57000000 #883c3c3c" />
  <ColorOption id="1" displayName="color_theme_1" colors="#8ecae6 #219ebc #ffb703 #fb8500 #883c3c3c" />
  <ColorOption id="2" displayName="color_theme_2" colors="#ff595e #ffca3a #8ac926 #1982c4 #883c3c3c" />
  <ColorOption id="3" displayName="color_theme_3" colors="#ff0000 #00ff00 #ff00ff #00ffff #883c3c3c" />
  <ColorOption id="4" displayName="color_theme_4" colors="#ff99c8 #fcf6bd #d0f4de #a9def9 #883c3c3c" />
  <ColorOption id="5" displayName="color_theme_5" colors="#1be7ff #6eeb83 #e4ff1a #ffb800 #883c3c3c" />
</ColorConfiguration>

<ImageConfiguration id="backgroundImage" displayName="back" defaultValue="20">
  <ImageOption id="20" displayName="g1" resource="@drawable/kadran3" />
  <ImageOption id="21" displayName="g2" resource="@drawable/kadran2" />
</ImageConfiguration>

<Scene>
<PartImage x="0" y="0" width="450" height="450" alpha="255">
<Image resource="[CONFIGURATION.backgroundImage]" />

  

ColorConfiguration customization in code works fine, ImageConfiguration does not work
 <PartImage x="0" y="0" width="450" ​​height="450" ​​alpha="255"> <Image resource="kadran3" /> </PartImage>

When I put a fixed image like this, it works.

I might be wrong, but I think there is no "ImageConfiguration", try to replace it with "ListConfiguration" and the "ImageOption" with "ListOption", check: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/wff/user-configuration/flavor
